# Wordpress - where should I place editable CSS

Tags: wordpress

Where do I place things like header's image, background color, background image...? Should I simply add them to html code? Or add pieces of the CSS to functions.php?

Also, when I add some code to head section from functions.php - will this be loaded automatically, or should I add something more to the head section myself?

Comment: place your CSS in style.css file..is this not the case ? what does "editable CSS" means ?? theme options ?

Comment: In the wordpress backend there is a place to edit the user generated CSS.

Comment: Yes, theme options, e.g. <header style="height:<?php get_header_height(); ?>">...I can't use php inside of the .css file.

Answer (score 1):

you can change style.css for any css change 
and header.php for header section,footer.php for footer section 
for home content index.php file

you can call function from function.php file in to these files

Answer (score 0):

If the theme you are using already has the HTML, then just modify the style.css.  If the theme doesn't support the image placements that you want, you can either try to modify the HTML files yourself, or ask the theme creator to add it for you.  If you modify this yourself, you'll have to remember that future updates to the theme may overwrite your changes.

If you are creating your own theme and don't care about flexibility, then add a spot in the HTML using your  tags.